# Replace every back slash in a JavaScript string with a different character

Tags: javascript, string, replace, backslash

How can I replace every \ character in a JavaScript string with a different character without using template literals?

An example of myString:

```
let myString = "This\ \is \\ my \\\\\String";
```

I have tried using the line: `let result = myString.replace(/\\/g, "-");`
However, this replaces every 2 back slashes with a dash

I have tried using the line: `let result = myString.replace(/\/g, "-");`
However, this produces an error

I have tried using the `String.raw()` function. However, this only works on Template Literal Strings. I am not able to use template literals

Comment: `myString.replace(/\\/g, "-");` Works for me exactly as it should

Comment: How does `myString` look like?

Comment: Your problem is not with the replacement but with the string literal syntax of `"This\ \is \\ my \\\\\String"`. That has only three backslashes, it represents the string `This is \ my \\String` which can be written in JS as `"This is \\ my \\\\String"` or ``String.raw`This is \ my \\String` ``. If you want extra backslashes, you need to actually put them in the string in the first place, and use the appropriate escaping if writing them in literal form.

Comment: Are you aware that backslashes are used for special [escaping syntax](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Escape_character) in JavaScript string literals?

Comment: If your string has escaped backslashes replace them with "--" and you'll have replaced every "\\" with a "--", but you'll remove any single "\" without replacing it.

Answer (score 0):

Single backslashes (`\`) in a string literal are interpreted as [character escapes](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/how-to-escape-strings-in-javascript). Every `\` that's not a character escape should be escaped on itself.

```js
// in myString, \ , \i and \S are interpreted as escape sequences
const myString = "This\ \is \\ my \\\\\String";;
// so this won't work as you may expect
console.log(myString.replace(/\\/g, `-`));

// every '\' should be escaped on itself in a string literal
const myStringOk = "This\\ \\is \\\\ my \\\\String";;
// now it works
console.log(myStringOk.replace(/\\/g, `-`));
```

Comment: Every individual back slash should be replaced with a dash, including the back slashes connected to a word or a different character

Comment: I'm sorry to say: in a string literal ("...", '...' or \`...\`) individual (single) backslashes can *not* be replaced - because ... well, see the answer.

Comment: Is there a way to convert the String Literal into a Raw String where the backslash has no meaning?

Comment: *Is there a way to convert the String Literal ...*.  No. There is no way to do that. Sorry again.